# Stata - Create within group ids

Tags: stata, identifier, pairwise

I have a data set of flows between locations, say they are 50 locations, but the number of pairs is not even because some locations do not have flows. I would like to create ids for each pair of observation (w_id and h_id)

Thank you.

> Desired output
>
> w_code             h_code          w_id  h_id
>
> 295101011001003    291892204451015 1   1
>
> 295101011001003    295101011001003 1   2
>
> 295101011001003    291892202003011 1   3
>
> 295101011001025    295101021003001 2   1
>
> 295101011001025    295101011001025 2   2
>
> 295101011001026    291879507003038 3   1
>
> 295101011001026    190130007001013 3   2
>
> 295101011001026    295101105001027 3   3
>
> 295101011001026    291892126002008 3   4
>
> 295101011001026    291892126001005 3   5
>
> 295101011001029    291892199006006 4   1
>
> 295101011002007    295101011002015 5   1
>
> 295101011002014    295101011002016 6   1
>
> 295101011002014    295101011001003 6   2
>
> 295101011002016    295101011001007 7   1
>
> 295101011002030    295101255001008 8   1

Answer (score 0):

Documentation accessible through Stata includes [this paper on composite categorical variables](https://www.stata-journal.com/sjpdf.html?articlenum=dm0034) and [this paper on handling dyadic data](https://www.stata-journal.com/sjpdf.html?articlenum=dm0043). The Stata command `search` would have led to these papers, except that the art to finding as well as searching is thinking of the right keywords.

In your case the natural question arises whether for example the pair (1, 2) is really the same as (2, 1) and for flows my guess is No. In mathematics, abstraction is often the key to solving a problem; in statistical computing some concreteness may make a problem clearer. Perhaps `h` means husband and `w` means wife, and perhaps not. Assuming that (1, 2) and (2, 1) are quite different, a joint identifier is immediately obtained by

```
 egen newid = group(w_id h_id)
```

and for a small number of identifiers -- you mention 50 -- there is no pain in asking for values to be labelled, so that with

```
egen newid = group(w_id h_id), label
```

the pair (1, 1) would be mapped to the value `1` and the value label `1 1`.

As this solution was not immediately obvious, it is likely that a study of `help egen` will reveal a bunch of tools likely to be useful in data management; some are directly statistical.

For pairs of identifiers where `Billy, Bob` is to be treated like `Bob, Billy` see the second paper linked above. Whether this is true for the OP is a little unclear, but it is likely to be true for some others reading this in the future.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. This command creates an id for each pair, what I wanted was an id for each combination of pairs. I used the proc sql and distinct option in SAS.

Comment: What's a combination of pairs? The issue is whether `1 2` and `2 1` are the same or different.